# Questions should request opinions of experts or denomination-survey, but not both

Tags: discussion

I think this question:

[Is John the Baptist a Christian Martyr?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/93425/is-john-the-baptist-a-christian-martyr)

needs editing, we have a lot of different Christian perspectives on the site, one needs to be specified.

Mainly the problem with the question is that it requires the answers to define the word martyr.  A denomination survey is pretty simple and a little nuanced; only a few denominations keep tabs on saints the way Lutherans, Orthodox, Anglicans and Catholics do.  If you ask "experts" then you get to goof around with the question.

Unfortunately, nobody answered with the opinion of any experts so all we're left with is a bunch of opinions (aside from the top and bottom answers which cite Catholic observances).

Who are experts anyway and why would anyone care what they have to say?  All I can think of is a guy on the Discovery channel sitting in a chair saying "John the Baptist is not a Martyr because ... (and then I fall asleep)".

I'd like to update this question to remove requests from 'experts' and delete most of the answers, but I would like to solicit a few opinions on the matter first.

Comment: I don't really think limiting it to either experts or denomination-survey would make it a good question. It's just fundamentally a matter of opinion, even if you were to limit it one of those ways.

Comment: I think I explained why it's not a matter of opinion to Catholics, for one thing, when you pray the office for August 29th, you read from the "Common of One Martyr" therefore he's a Martyr.  The problem is not everyone knows that words like martyr have concrete meanings in some denominations, convoluted meanings in others and no meaning in some.  So you can still answer it in a denomination survey manner, you just say, "whereas Evangelicals don't have a definition of Martyr they might consider ..."

Comment: Is there an official Catholic source that calls him a "Christian Martyr"? Simply being called a martyr wouldn't count enough, I think.

Comment: I closed it as opinion based. If it's made more objective it can be reopened.

Comment: @curiousdannii ahh, that's the nuance of the question that seems irrelevant to most Catholics, but I see it now. We consider David and the Patriarchs Saints too,  there's no distinction between Christian Saints and Saints in the eternal sense and there's no point in thinking about Saints except in the eternal sense.

Comment: Hah. I thought it was obvious that the whole question was about whether or not John the Baptist was a Christian or not. Catholics should care however, because the blessings of the New Covenant surpass the old in so many ways. If you treat OT saints the same as NT saints then you risk minimising all the blessings of Christ and the Gospel.

Comment: I thought the reason we say "Jesus descended to hell" in the creed was because Jesus brought the Good News to them all sometime (outside of time) between Friday and Saturday afternoon. There may be more glory in Heaven for NT saints, but that's God's business.

Comment: Well yeah, they all believe in Jesus now. Doesn't mean that they're members of the New Covenant however. But that's getting into some deep and disputed theology ;)